# jquery ui adding unnecessary code and breaking things

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay so I've been working on saving a resized element using local storage

when you load the page the ui code is added to the resize div.
And at first you can resize the element but if you save it and refresh the page the resize ui code is added again which breaks it. I know I could just run replace before saving, but I was wondering if there are any other more efficient ways.

code added more than once.
http://jsfiddle.net/code_cookies/Spkzq/95/

```
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se"     style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
```

JS:

```
if (localStorage.pins === "") { 
    $('#draggable').html('<div id="image"class="resize" style="padding:20px; width:200px; height:200px; background-color:white;"><img class="" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://i48.tinypic.com/31368e9.jpg"/></div>');
}
else { 
    $('#draggable').html(localStorage.pins);
}
$("#image").resizable();
$('#save').click(function() {
    localStorage.pins = $('#draggable').html();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove everything that jquery UI has added by calling `destroy`:

```
$("#image").resizable( "destroy" );
```

Comment: Fiddle using this method http://jsfiddle.net/Spkzq/97/ ( was about to answer with it, :)  )